# .htaccess can't add directory slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I've been trying to rewrite my php URLs with .htaccess so that they are more SEO/user friendly. Here is my code:

```
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/contact$ /contact?lang=$1 [L]
```

What this does is, it turns this:

```
http://www.example.com/?lang=en
http://www.example.com/contact?lang=en
```

Into this:

```
http://www.example.com/en/
http://www.example.com/en/contact
```

**The problem:**

```
http://www.example.com/en/
```

is not the same thing as:

```
http://www.example.com/en
```

And I get a `404 Not Found` error when I try to point my browser's address to `http://www.example.com/en`. How can I make both versions of this work?

Adding `DirectorySlashes On` to my `root` .htaccess did not work. But my mobile version located in the `/m/` folder has the following .htaccess:

```
# Set dir index
DirectoryIndex index.php
# Set dir slashes
DirectorySlash On
```

And it works! When I visit `http://www.example.com/m` I get redirected to `http://www.example.com/m/`. That is the wanted behavior. I guess it works because `/m/` is a sub directory...

**The question:**

How can I make `http://www.example.com/en` redirect to `http://www.example.com/en/` without breaking the rest of my URLs?

**Edit (my entire `.htaccess`):**

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /
# Disable directory views
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
# Follow Symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Create Directory Slashes
DirectorySlash On
# Rewrite urls
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Pretty desktop URLs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/prices$ /prices?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/offers$ /offers?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/maps$ /maps?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/contact$ /contact?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/links$ /links?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/error$ /error?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/verify-new$ /verify-new?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/verify-old$ /verify-old?lang=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^en/ski-rent-prices$ /ski-rent-prices [L]
    # Rewrite mobile URLs
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/m/$ /m/?lang=$1 [L]
    # WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    # Rewrite URL without file extensions
    # For .PHP files
    RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^offers$ offers.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^prices$ prices.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^maps$ maps.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^links$ links.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^verify-new$ verify-new.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^verify-old$ verify-old.php [L]
    # For .PDF files
    RewriteRule ^ski-rent-prices$ ski-rent-prices.pdf [L]
</IfModule>
# Add Custom Error pages
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
# Default Character set
IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Hide the server signature
ServerSignature Off
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Add correct content types for documents
    # JS:
    AddType text/javascript .js
    # CSS:
    AddType text/css .js
    # TXT:
    AddType text/plain .txt
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # IE Compability Mode
    BrowserMatch (MSIE|Trident) ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    # Disallow 3rd party iframes
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

Comment: DirectorySlash is turned on by default on apache servers

Comment: I think your first rule doesn't match **/en**

Comment: Yes, it doesn't and that is the problem. My question is how to make it match **/xy** where `xy` is any of the languages my PHP files `GET` from the URL.

Comment: DirectorSlash has nothing to do with the issue you are having. actually you have to make the trailing slash optional in your rule so that the /en or /en/ both can work.

Answer (score 1):

## Rewrite --- www.example.com/?lang=en => www.example.com/en/

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=en($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /en/? [L,R]
```

Comment: My PHP scripts `GET` the `lang` parameter's value and use it to translate the page. I just gave an example with `http://www.example.com/en/`. I have 3 languages on my site so I need a universal piece of code to match all 3 of them (`en`, `ru`, `de`). So I will also need to rewrite `/ru/` and `/de/` too.

Answer (score 1):

Updated code for testing

```
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)/(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ ?lang=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)/(.+)/m/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/ $2?lang=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/m/ $2/m/?lang=$1 [L,R=301]
```

See the browser address bar and check if the redirections are correct. If it wrong provide the source link and redirected link. If it is ok, Then use the below code.

```
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)/(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ ?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)/(.+)/m/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/ $2?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/m/ $2/m/?lang=$1 [L]
```

I have tried the code with the below links and its working fine.

```
http://www.example.com/en
http://www.example.com/en/
http://www.example.com/en/contact
http://www.example.com/en/contact/
http://www.example.com/en/contact/m
http://www.example.com/en/contact/m/
http://www.example.com/en/prices
http://www.example.com/en/prices/
http://www.example.com/en/prices/m
http://www.example.com/en/prices/m/
```

Check these links yourself and also other links as well.

Comment: Now the `/en` -> `/en/` works but any other page that uses rewrites gives `404 Not Found`.

Comment: @JohnyP. After this code, what URL is giving you 404?

Comment: Yes it does. I posted my entire `.htaccess` in the question so that you can see if there's conflicting code.

Comment: Oh I didn't read that well... All of the rewritten URLs give me 404... like `contact` for example.

Comment: For testing purposes change all `[L]` to `[L,R=301]` and tell me the link you have tried and the link to which the it was redirected to(see the browser address bar).

Comment: Also, is your real location for contact  `http://www.example.com/contact.php` or `http://www.example.com/contact/index.php`. Which is it ?

Comment: @Rijul I'm glad you deleted your duplicate answer on another post. Please do the same for the rest of your contributions: edit one of your answers on each question to be a full answer, and delete the other answer(s). In a few days I'll start downvoting your duplicate answers.

Comment: @Andras Deak Done what you asked.

Comment: @Rijul Going to test these when I come back home.

Comment: `508 Loop Detected.` @Rijul

Comment: Thanks, @Rijul, I really appreciate it:) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Johny for which link you got `508 Loop Detected`? and which all links worked perfectly for you from the list I gave above?

Comment: All of them gave me a 508.